# Can't delete file or folders with "delete key" when on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop interface

Tags: keyboard, gnome-shell, delete, interface, 20.04

I have a problem that "delete key" on keyboard doesn't work when on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop interface. I can use "delete key" when on desktop interface of Ubuntu 19.10 and it works well, but on Ubuntu 20.04 "delete key" on keyboard doesn't do anything. What is the solution, is this a bug?

Comment: Similar to this problem, having a workaround : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04/1231791#comment2073363_1231791

Comment: Answered here https://askubuntu.com/a/1240666/24700

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)